# How to use Netty for RTSP server/client

Tags: java, video-streaming, netty, rtsp, rtsp-client

I have added netty 3.2.9.Final jar in maven pom for my java web application. but I really don't know how to use it in my application. I read alot about RTSP protocol but didn't understood how to create or use RTSP server/client using netty.

So can anyone help me to implement RTSP server / client solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The RTSP protocol is based on HTTP, so you should be able to re use most of what is already there in terms of HTTP support. Start with the HTTP examples.